# KML layer doesn't match with map shape in Android Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, kml

I am developing an android app and I am using **Google Maps Android API** to show a **KML layer** I made with ArcGIS over Spain. I created this layer with ArcGIS by exporting a File Geodatabase Raster Dataset to KML. The spatial reference of the file in ArcGIS was in ED_1950_UTM_Zone_30N (Projected Coordinate System) and has the shape of Spain.

**Problem:** The layer is displaying correctly in my app map but **the shape of the layer do not match perfectly with the shape of the country** (see images attached) However, when I open this KML in both PC Windows Desktop and Android versions of Google Earth the KML layer adjusts perfectly to the country map boundaries.

I have reported this issue in GitHub but had no answers: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/394

This is the piece of code where I add the KML layer:

```
try {
                    mMap.clear();
                    KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(mMap, R.raw.kriging_sqri, getApplicationContext());
                    layer.addLayerToMap();
                    mapModeKML = true;
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

And this is the content of my kriging_sqri.kml file, located in res/raw:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2 http://code.google.com/apis/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd">
<Document id="Kriging_shp3_Clip">
  <name>Kriging_shp3_Clip</name>
  <Snippet></Snippet>
  <GroundOverlay id="0">
    <Snippet></Snippet>
    <drawOrder>1000</drawOrder>
    <name>Kriging_shp3_Clip</name>
    <Icon>
      <href>file:///storage/emulated/0/BioApp/Layer0.png</href>
      <viewBoundScale>1.0</viewBoundScale>
    </Icon>
    <LatLonBox>
      <north>44.67706278743195</north>
      <south>35.085026094869</south>
      <east>6.152473147346782</east>
      <west>-10.78014121100213</west>
      <rotation>0</rotation>
    </LatLonBox>
  </GroundOverlay>
</Document>
</kml>
```

This is how my app displays the KML layer (notice how its shape does not match with the country land boundaries, specially remarkable on its south and east coast).
[image: This is how my app displays the KML layer (notice how its shape does not match with the country land boundaries, specially remarkable on its south and east coast.]

But this same KML is correctly displayed in Google Earth applications (I've tried it on Desktop and Android versions). This is how it looks in Android app of Google Earth:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

When exporting to KML, you should always convert your data to WGS84 (EPSG 4326) first. Try reprojecting your data and then exporting to KML again.  If that doesn't work, let us know, and please share a copy of both the new KML and the image file ("Layer0.png" in your sample above), so that we can see the data and help debug.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it and post a comment to share the results.